# How to generate defaults for laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a problem with generating default roles and permissions in laravel 5.6 with spatie's plugin for authorization.

I've done almost everything ok, expect this one annoying thing: I don't know how to generate like a default values, to even access view in which I could add myself a role with permissions...

I am talking about the code of Commands/GenerateRoles.php, which looks just like here: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131443/laravel-5-5-permissions-user-does-not-have-the-right-roles)

I mean: where to type that code and how to run it.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: You really want to start reading the docs on the console command artisan: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan - after that, you should understand how it works enough to try it out yourself. Good luck!

Comment: I think [Database Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding) is really what you're after.